# Angular Material Table with object as datasource

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

My component looks like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Member} from '../entities/Member'; 
import { SearchService } from './search.service';

@Component({   
  selector: 'app-search',   
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',   
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  members: Member[] = [];  
  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchService.getPartenaires().subscribe(
        member=> {
          this.members= member;
        }
    );   
  } 
}
```

I haven't figured out how to display my objects on a material table using `ngFor`. the examples on https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview are always using arrays as DataSource.

Should I put my objects into an array before passing them to the HTML? or is there a way to loop through them? thanks.

Comment: yes you need to push all your objects in array then pass to html.

Comment: Provide the sample data!

Comment: You can use this https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/

Comment: @RidRoid one of the reason is 'ngFor' is working on array not in object

Answer (score 1):

In order to work with `Angular Material Table` you need to first import `MatTableModule`
 module from `import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';`
 into your `app.module.ts` (in case you want to use other functionalities like `MatSort` you have to include them as well. Then in your DOM file you should add the template for your table and table columns like following:

```html
<table #dataTable mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<!-- COLUMN INFO -->
 <!--ID Col -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!--Name Col -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

<!-- ROW Info-->
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let rowData; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

After this in your `component.ts` file you need to do three things:

- define the column names you want to be displayed (they should match the `matColumnDef` in DOM File)
- Introduce your data source to the mat table
- call the `renderRows()` on the data table

bare in mind that this will automatically iterate through your data source array and will populate the table you don't need any `*ngFor`. Just keep your data source as `Array` of `Objects`.

```html
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTable, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit }
export class DocumentListComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('dataTable') dataTable: MatTable<any>;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ItemModel> ;
  columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'name'];
  ngOnInit() {
      let dataSamples: ItemModel[] ;
      //init your list with ItemModel Objects (can be manual or come from server etc) And put it in data source
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ItemModel>(dataSamples);
      if(this.dataSource){
            this.dataTable.renderRows();
      }
  }
}
export class ItemModel {
name: string;
id: number;
}
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't work with me, ViewChild dataTable doesn't know "renderRows()" :(